# When I am going to install Magento in my xampp server having following issue, please help

Tags: localhost, xampp

> [ERROR] LogicException: Unknown module in the requested list:
>   'TemplateMonster_AjaxCatalog' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php:429
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(388):
>   Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->readListOfModules(Array, Array,
>   'enable_modules') #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(334):
>   Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->createModulesConfig(Array, true) #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Controller\Install.php(109):
>   Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array) #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(84):
>   Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction() #4 [internal
>   function]:
>   Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
>    #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(490):
>   call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #6
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(260):
>   Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch',
>   Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #7
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractController.php(118):
>   Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure),
>   Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #8
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\DispatchListener.php(118):
>   Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request),
>   Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response)) #9 [internal function]:
>   Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #10
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(490):
>   call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #11
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(260):
>   Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch',
>   Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #12
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Application.php(340):
>   Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure),
>   Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #13
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\setup\index.php(35):
>   Zend\Mvc\Application->run() #14 {main}

Comment: Are you use fresh magento setup?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you already have the file app/etc/config.php and inside of that file is probably `TemplateMonster_AjaxCatalog`. If you are doing a fresh install you can simply delete that file OR you can find the line containing `TemplateMonster_AjaxCatalog` and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Just be sure you are importing all the modules from Live server or use cli to disable not used modules in local.